# R: grouping and expanding the data.frame to include only possible pairs of names in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, combinations, expand

My goal is to `expand` my data.frame in `R` to include possible combinations (but not all possible combinations) from a column in R. Similar to the `expand.grid` command, but that function gives you all possible combinations, not just what is present.

To start, I need to group by each factor in the 1st column, and keep the information included in column 2. In column 3, I have character strings of the names of 'Animals'. I want to find each possible pair that occur in this column, row by row (but not all possible pairs). For example, if I have 'Dreadwing' and 'Scorcher' in the first two rows - that would be one pair: Dreadwing-Scorcher and it should not include Scorcher-Dreadwing. However, if rows 4 and five are T-Rex and T-Rex, the pair should appear once: T-Rex-T-Rex because T-Rex appears in 2 separate rows of the column 'Animals.' If T-Rex were to appear in 3 separate rows, then the pair should appear 3 times, etc., etc.

Lastly, pairs should expand the data.frame by 2 columns to store the pairs. In other words, the Dreadwing and Scorcher pair should be each in their own separate column, but in the same row.

I have manually put together this picture to show what my output should be from the data.frame I have (note: Area_1 and Area_2 are separated only to fit the results in one screenshot). The left: I have put arrows showing the desired combinations just from the first row, Dreadwing. On the right: the desired result for all of Area_1 and Area_2.

[image]

For the desired result, for Area_1, the Dreadwing-Dreadwing pair should not occur bc Dreadwing does not appear in any other row for Area_1. However, T-Rex appears in 2 separate rows, so the combination of T-Rex-T-Rex should be there, as well as the combination of each row of T-Rex combining with each row of Waterwing. So, 4 T-Rex-Waterwing combinations.

**Reproducible Data**

*Creating the data.frame*

```
v <- c(rep("Area_1", 7), rep("Area_2", 7))
w <- c(rep("Forest", 7), rep("Cave", 7))
y <- c("Waterwing", "Scorcher", "Snapmaw", "T-Rex", "T-Rex", "Dreadwing", 
"Waterwing", "Snake", "T-Rex", "T-Rex", "Dreadwing", "Snapmaw", "Scorcher", 
"Waterwing")

stack_df <- data.frame(Area = v, Location = w, Animals = y)
stack_df <- stack_df[order(stack_df$Area, stack_df$Location, stack_df$Animals), ]
row.names(stack_df) <- 1:nrow(stack_df)
```

Using the [tidyR guidebook](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html), I have found that the command `expand` in conjunction with the `nesting` command (to keep only combinations that appear in the data) does not work. For example:

```
library(tidyr)    
stack_df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Area) %>%
    expand(nesting(Location, Animals, Animals))
```

will return only 11/14 rows.

I have tried multiple ways using the `expand` and `crossing` command. However, like the `expand.grid` command, these commands give you all possible combinations.

Despite this, using the `expand` command is the closest I have gotten to what I am aiming for.

```
stack_df %>%
dplyr::group_by(Area) %>%
expand(Location, Animals, Animals)
```

As you can see, all possibilities are included, which is not the desired result.

Any ideas on how I can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds/looks to me like you want to find all combinations (within the Area/Location group) of pairs of Animals where the 1st Animal in the pair occurs on a row before the 2nd Animal in the pair.

We can do this by adding a row number index and doing a self-join with an inequality constraint on the row numbers. (This requires `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0)

```
library(dplyr)
stack_df = stack_df |>
  mutate(group_i = row_number(), .by = c(Area, Location))

stack_df |>
  inner_join(
    stack_df,
    by = join_by(Area, Location, group_i < group_i),
    suffix = c("..2", "..3")  
  ) |>
  select(-starts_with("group_"))
#      Area Location Animals..2 Animals..3
# 1  Area_1   Forest  Dreadwing   Scorcher
# 2  Area_1   Forest  Dreadwing    Snapmaw
# 3  Area_1   Forest  Dreadwing      T-Rex
# 4  Area_1   Forest  Dreadwing      T-Rex
# 5  Area_1   Forest  Dreadwing  Waterwing
# 6  Area_1   Forest  Dreadwing  Waterwing
# 7  Area_1   Forest   Scorcher    Snapmaw
# 8  Area_1   Forest   Scorcher      T-Rex
# 9  Area_1   Forest   Scorcher      T-Rex
# 10 Area_1   Forest   Scorcher  Waterwing
# 11 Area_1   Forest   Scorcher  Waterwing
# 12 Area_1   Forest    Snapmaw      T-Rex
# 13 Area_1   Forest    Snapmaw      T-Rex
# 14 Area_1   Forest    Snapmaw  Waterwing
# 15 Area_1   Forest    Snapmaw  Waterwing
# 16 Area_1   Forest      T-Rex      T-Rex
# 17 Area_1   Forest      T-Rex  Waterwing
# 18 Area_1   Forest      T-Rex  Waterwing
# 19 Area_1   Forest      T-Rex  Waterwing
# 20 Area_1   Forest      T-Rex  Waterwing
# 21 Area_1   Forest  Waterwing  Waterwing
# 22 Area_2     Cave  Dreadwing   Scorcher
# 23 Area_2     Cave  Dreadwing      Snake
# 24 Area_2     Cave  Dreadwing    Snapmaw
# 25 Area_2     Cave  Dreadwing      T-Rex
# 26 Area_2     Cave  Dreadwing      T-Rex
# 27 Area_2     Cave  Dreadwing  Waterwing
# 28 Area_2     Cave   Scorcher      Snake
# 29 Area_2     Cave   Scorcher    Snapmaw
# 30 Area_2     Cave   Scorcher      T-Rex
# 31 Area_2     Cave   Scorcher      T-Rex
# 32 Area_2     Cave   Scorcher  Waterwing
# 33 Area_2     Cave      Snake    Snapmaw
# 34 Area_2     Cave      Snake      T-Rex
# 35 Area_2     Cave      Snake      T-Rex
# 36 Area_2     Cave      Snake  Waterwing
# 37 Area_2     Cave    Snapmaw      T-Rex
# 38 Area_2     Cave    Snapmaw      T-Rex
# 39 Area_2     Cave    Snapmaw  Waterwing
# 40 Area_2     Cave      T-Rex      T-Rex
# 41 Area_2     Cave      T-Rex  Waterwing
# 42 Area_2     Cave      T-Rex  Waterwing
```

Comment: Such an elegant solution! Not only did this work beautifully for my data, but this answer also kept track of all additional columns in my real data with the `suffix = c("..2", "..3")` flag. Thank-you very much. I am marking this as the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have R > 4.3, there is a small package on github that I use to do multiple tests.

```
# devtools::install_github('oonyambu/SLR')

stack_df %>%
    mutate(Area = paste(Area, Location), z = 1) %>%
    SLR::multiple_tests(z~Animals|Area, ., \(x,y)list(NULL)) %>%
    separate(Area, c('Area', 'Location'), sep = ' ') %>%
    separate(Value, c('Animal1', 'Animal2'), sep = ':')
     Area Location response   Animal1   Animal2
1  Area_1   Forest        z Dreadwing  Scorcher
2  Area_1   Forest        z Dreadwing   Snapmaw
3  Area_1   Forest        z Dreadwing     T-Rex
4  Area_1   Forest        z Dreadwing Waterwing
5  Area_1   Forest        z  Scorcher   Snapmaw
6  Area_1   Forest        z  Scorcher     T-Rex
7  Area_1   Forest        z  Scorcher Waterwing
8  Area_1   Forest        z   Snapmaw     T-Rex
9  Area_1   Forest        z   Snapmaw Waterwing
10 Area_1   Forest        z     T-Rex Waterwing
11 Area_2     Cave        z Dreadwing  Scorcher
12 Area_2     Cave        z Dreadwing     Snake
13 Area_2     Cave        z Dreadwing   Snapmaw
14 Area_2     Cave        z Dreadwing     T-Rex
15 Area_2     Cave        z Dreadwing Waterwing
16 Area_2     Cave        z  Scorcher     Snake
17 Area_2     Cave        z  Scorcher   Snapmaw
18 Area_2     Cave        z  Scorcher     T-Rex
19 Area_2     Cave        z  Scorcher Waterwing
20 Area_2     Cave        z     Snake   Snapmaw
21 Area_2     Cave        z     Snake     T-Rex
22 Area_2     Cave        z     Snake Waterwing
23 Area_2     Cave        z   Snapmaw     T-Rex
24 Area_2     Cave        z   Snapmaw Waterwing
25 Area_2     Cave        z     T-Rex Waterwing
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for introducing me to the new packages. I'll have to keep them in mind. However, the answer I am seeking is all present combinations. This path omits the repeats that I need - for example, the 4 T-Rex-Waterwing combos in Area_1. Total rows for what I'm needing should be 42.

Comment: @Purrsia in that case, you do not group by area, meaning you change the formula to `z~Animals`